# Google BigQuery "bq" tool extracts nested/repeated records, how with Java's API?

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery

I've created a Google BigQuery table with five nested/repeated records,
 when I try queries 
`...bigquery.jobs().query(projectId, queryRequest).execute();... 
then 
...queryResponse.getRows()...`, BigQuery returns a flat json.
I've seen that the `python bq --extract` tool, is able to return pretty well the json.
This json, effectively, is exactly the json that I've loaded.
How is it possible with Java's API?
Can someone help me, please?
Thanks
Onofrio

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery flattens the results of all queries. We've had a feature request for a while to provide the option to *not* flatten query results, and we may add support for this in the future.

If you want to read nested data from a table, however, you can use `bigquery.tabledata().list(...)`, which will return nested/repeated json.

Comment: Jordan, thanks for your response. If I use TableDataList queryResult = bigquery.tabledata().list(...).execute(); as you say, and then List<TableRow> rows = queryResult.getRows(); the result is always flat. I've tried all methods of queryResult but I'm not able to return nested/repeated json.